# I can't do anything with an array of arrays of objects in my react app

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I collect some data from various urls into an array, using a for loop:

```
let data3;
const getPhotosData = async (album) => {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${album}/photos`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const jsonRes = await res.json();
  return jsonRes;
};

let data = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
const promise = getPhotosData(i);
promise.then((items) => {
  data.push(items);
  
});
data3 = data;
 }
```

if I log `data3` to the console, I'll get an array with multiple arrays of 50 objects each, but if I log `data3.length` I get 0, and of course i can't perform any iterations on it like, `map`, `flat` or `forEach` (what i want is to flatten data3 into a single array of objects).

I tried defining `data3` as a state variable and then only flatten it (or even just get its's length), after setting it's value inside a `useEffect` hook, with `data` inside dependency array (or dependency array empty), but got same results.

Comment: post the data3 values

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka it's too long to post, there's 100 arrays inside, each containing 50 objects. example: albumId: 1
id: 1
thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
title: "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt"
url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c9

Comment: Don't post all values. Instead, make a [mcve]. In other words: copy only as much as needed to illustrate the question. Also, [edit] the post with additional information, don't post it as a comment. Finally: don't add links to off-site data or code, but post it as text within the question itself.

Comment: where exactly do you console.log it and where do you see the 0 length?

Comment: @Apostolos i logged it all around the code. i get 0, simply by typing `console.log(data3.length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to wait for all promises to finish, and then assign the result to your `data3` variable.
Then, use `flat()` and you'll get the result you want.

```js
let data3;
const getPhotosData = async (album) => {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${album}/photos`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const jsonRes = await res.json();
  return jsonRes;
};

let promises = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  promises.push(getPhotosData(i));
}
 
 Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
  data3 = values;
  console.log(data3.length, data3.flat().length);
});
```

Comment: now this is the closest to solving my problem, i effectively get `data3.flat().length` of 5000 as expected, but then when i try to use it in another hook like that: `  let dataToMap;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataToSearch === 'todos') {
      dataToMap = data1;
    } else if (dataToSearch === 'posts') {
      dataToMap = data2;
    } else if (dataToSearch === 'photos') {
      dataToMap = data3;
      console.log(data3, data3.length());
    }
    
  }, [dataToSearch]);
` then i still get an empty array.

Comment: thanks guys, i used @apostolos answer, but inside a `useEffect` hook, it works almost great, except the data is not fetched at first attempt only at second.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that javascript does not wait for asynchronous code to complete before going further in execution.

Reading or watching videos on code execution in javascript (event loop, call stack) will help a lot.

In this case, you're not waiting for the promise to be fulfilled and then console.log - so your code is putting out a length of 0 for data3 because the promises are not resolved yet(the API calls haven't been finished and therefore `data.push(items);` this code hasn't run yet).

So one way to solve this is your exact same code but you need to put an await to promise.then as shown here

```
const getData = async () => {
  let data3;
  const getPhotosData = async (album) => {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${album}/photos`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const jsonRes = await res.json();
    return jsonRes;
  };

  let data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    const promise = getPhotosData(i);
    await promise.then((items) => {
      data.push(items);
    });
    data3 = data;
  }
  console.log("data3 - ", data3);
};

getData()
```

If however you're using this in react.js context and want the data to be loaded and then use it in the page

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const getData = async () => {
  let data3;
  const getPhotosData = async (album) => {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${album}/photos`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const jsonRes = await res.json();
    return jsonRes;
  };

  let data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    const promise = getPhotosData(i);
    await promise.then((items) => {
      data.push(items);
    });
    data3 = data;
  }
  return data3;
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const dataResult = await getData();
      setData(dataResult);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (data.length === 0) return <div>...loading</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Keep in mind to read about promises and async/await which is basically a sugar syntax of promises.
Also your code could be optimized but that's beyond the scope of this question.
Working example of your code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-knuth-hem5kp?file=/src/App.js:701-728)

Comment: hi, thanks for that, your answer is making total sense, yet when I try to work with my new `data3`, mainly to `.flat()`ten it or even get `.length` from it, i'm back to square one, can't do flat (it says it's not a function) and i get length 0. Doesn't matter where i do it, either inside the `useEffect` where i `setData3` or anywhere else, like inside different `useEffect` or just anywhere.

Comment: No problemo. If you want to get good at this try reading about code execution in javascript (call stack, event loop) and Promises, Async/await. And rewatch it multiple times since it's a bit hard to understand but once there you won't have these kinds of problems.

Comment: @chylinski also for it to make the list flat in the provided solution you would just have to change


`setData(dataResult);`
to
`setData(dataResult.flat());`

Comment: yeah, i've been struggling with these topics, hence i studied them like 150 times already, if i didn't i wouldn't be able to even  formulate the question, let alone find an answer.